# What is the numbering of substituted benzene derivatives according to IUPAC nomenclature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds

[image]

According to the lowest locant rule shouldn't the numbering of the compound **1** start from the carbon at the 4th position, thus giving the IUPAC name as **1,2-dimethyl-4-hydroxybenzene?**

For compound **2** they could have prioritized the functional group, but they have prioritized the lowest locant rule instead.

Comment: The functional group has the highest priority.

Comment: Agreed. But i can also find some other examples where the functional group is'nt given the priority.

Comment: Halides and nitro groups aren't considered to be functional groups in nomenclature, they are substituents, while a hydroxy group is a functional group e.g. you would never  say phenyl chloride or hydroxybenzene, while chlorobenzene and benzenol (phenol) are preferred names. Understand the difference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several criteria for the numbering of locants. The most important simplified criteria for the numbering for substituted benzene compounds are:

1. lower locants for the principal characteristic groups, which are expressed as a suffix or implied by the name of the functional parent compound (If there is a choice, the principal characteristic groups are assigned in accordance with the order of seniority of classes of compounds.)
2. lower locants for prefixes
3. lower locants for substituents cited first as a prefix in the name

The corresponding actual wording of the nomenclature rules (taken from *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*) reads as follows:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (c) principal characteristic groups and free valences (suffixes);
>
> (…)
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (g) lowest locants for the substituent cited first as a prefix in the name;
>
> (…)

The first compound given in the question has the functional parent compound phenol. The name ‘phenol’ implies the presence of the characteristic group $\ce{-OH}$. Since there are no other characteristic groups and low locants are assigned first to the principal characteristic group, the locant ‘1’ is assigned to the  substituent group $\ce{-OH}$. Therefore, the systematic name for this compound is **3,4-dimethylphenol**.

[image: 3,4-dimethylphenol]

The second compound given in the question does not have any principal characteristic group – neither expressed as a suffix nor implied by the name of a functional parent compound. Therefore, low locants are assigned to the prefixes ‘chloro’, ‘methyl’, and ‘nitro’, all considered together as a set in a series of increasing numerical order. Thus, the systematic name for this compound is **2-chloro-1-methyl-4-nitrobenzene** and neither ‘1-chloro-2-methyl-5-nitrobenzene’ nor ‘3-chloro-4-methyl-1-nitrobenzene’ since the locant set ‘1,2,4’ is lower than ‘1,2,5’ or ‘1,3,4’.

[image: 2-chloro-1-methyl-4-nitrobenzene]

Answer (score -2):

1. Lowest set locant rule is considered **after** prioritising the functional group (i.e. giving it the first position).
   so answer of the first question is **3,4-dimethylphenol**.
2. In the second question the answer given in the book is wrong . It should have been **3-chloro-4-methylnitrobenzene**