# IUPAC name of trisubstituted benzene ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

What is the IUPAC name for the compound shown below? I named it as 6-Bromo-3-hydroxy benzonitrile according to the numbering scheme in **1b**, since the priority order is $\ce{-CN} > \ce{-OH} > \ce{-Br}$.

However, the answer given in the book is 2-Bromo-5-hydroxy benzonitrile, which implies the numbering scheme in **1a**. Please help me to identify whether my answer or the book's answer is correct.

[image]

Comment: We compare the answer's [1,2,5] and your [1,3,6]. The first numbers (1 and 1) are the same; the second numbers (2 and 3) has the answer smaller than your attempt; therefore the answer is correct.

Comment: The priority order only determines which goes into the suffix.

Comment: Related (actually duplicate, but the other question is closed and includes proposed answers that are not related to the question): [IUPAC name of bromo, cyano, hydroxy substituted benzene ring](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59642/7951)

Comment: Also related: [What is the numbering of substituted benzene derivatives according to IUPAC nomenclature?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/53556/7951)

Comment: Numbering of carbons aside, there are two things I want to point out. Firstly, the first letter of the substituent should not be capitalised, so *bromo* is correct and not *Bromo*. Secondly, there is no space between the prefixes and the name of the parent compound, so there is no space between hydroxy and benzonitrile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As -CN has the highest priority, root-word is benzonitrile. Lowest locant is 2 for -Br.
So, the name given is:
2-bromo-5-hydroxybenzonitrile

As the functional group is -CN, with highest priority, no need to look for priority of -OH and -Br; just look for lowest locant.

[image: 2-bromo-5-hydroxybenzonitrile]

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that you would typically name this as a substituted phenol.  The name I would get for this is 4-bromo-3-cyanophenol.  Whether or not this is 'strictly' IUPAC I'm not sure.  When I searched this on Google, I found that SigmaAldrich was selling a constitutional isomer of this as 3-bromo-4-hydroxybenzonitrile, which would imply the previous answer is also acceptable.   Frankly, it doesn't strike me as a critically important issue for most applications, since both names are completely unambiguous.